# How to use bottom sheets with angular/material design?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I'm hoping someone can give me a hand on why this isn't working for me.

In the material design documentation it provides a code snippet to setup the bottom sheet feature with angular:

https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.bottomSheet

When I use this code in my own site, none of the buttons display and It is only showing {{alert}}

I have tried searching online for answers or tutorials but can't find any or even seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="BottomSheetExample">
  <p style="padding-left: 20px;">
    Bottom sheet can be dismissed with the service or a swipe down.
  </p>
  <div class="bottom-sheet-demo inset" layout="column" layout-sm="row" layout-align="center">
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
      Show as List
    </md-button>
    <div style="width:50px;"></div>
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="showGridBottomSheet($event)">
      Show as Grid
    </md-button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <b layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-margin>
    {{alert}}
  </b>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('bottomSheetDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('BottomSheetExample', function($scope, $timeout, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.alert = '';
  $scope.showListBottomSheet = function($event) {
    $scope.alert = '';
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-list-template.html',
      controller: 'ListBottomSheetCtrl',
      targetEvent: $event
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' clicked!';
    });
  };
  $scope.showGridBottomSheet = function($event) {
    $scope.alert = '';
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-grid-template.html',
      controller: 'GridBottomSheetCtrl',
      targetEvent: $event
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' clicked!';
    });
  };
})
.controller('ListBottomSheetCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Share', icon: 'share' },
    { name: 'Upload', icon: 'upload' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy' },
    { name: 'Print this page', icon: 'print' },
  ];
  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
})
.controller('GridBottomSheetCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Hangout', icon: 'hangout' },
    { name: 'Mail', icon: 'mail' },
    { name: 'Message', icon: 'message' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy' },
    { name: 'Facebook', icon: 'facebook' },
    { name: 'Twitter', icon: 'twitter' },
  ];
  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
});
```

CSS

```
.bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage {
  /* Temporary fix until md-icon is working, DO NOT USE! */ }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-list-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px; }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage .md-inline-list-icon-label {
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -5px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-list-icon[icon=share] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-list-icon[icon=upload] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-list-icon[icon=copy] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-list-icon[icon=print] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage .md-icon-container md-inline-grid-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px; }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-grid-icon[icon=hangout] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-grid-icon[icon=mail] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-grid-icon[icon=message] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-grid-icon[icon=copy] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iNDhweCINCgkgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNDggNDgiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDQ4IDQ4IiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj4NCjxnIGlkPSJIZWFkZXIiPg0KCTxnPg0KCQk8cmVjdCB4PSItODM4IiB5PSItMTcyMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgd2lkdGg9IjE0MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMzYwMCIvPg0KCTwvZz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnIGlkPSJMYWJlbHMiPg0KPC9nPg0KPGcgaWQ9Ikljb24iPg0KCTxnPg0KCQk8cmVjdCBmaWxsPSJub25lIiB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgiLz4NCgkJPHBhdGggZmlsbD0iIzdkN2Q3ZCIgZD0iTTMyLDJIOEM1LjgsMiw0LDMuOCw0LDZ2MjhoNFY2aDI0VjJ6IE0zOCwxMEgxNmMtMi4yLDAtNCwxLjgtNCw0djI4YzAsMi4yLDEuOCw0LDQsNGgyMmMyLjIsMCw0LTEuOCw0LTRWMTQNCgkJCUM0MiwxMS44LDQwLjIsMTAsMzgsMTB6IE0zOCw0MkgxNlYxNGgyMlY0MnoiLz4NCgk8L2c+DQo8L2c+DQo8ZyBpZD0iR3JpZCIgZGlzcGxheT0ibm9uZSI+DQoJPGcgZGlzcGxheT0iaW5saW5lIj4NCgkJPGxpbmUgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjMDBFNUZGIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjAuMSIgc3Ryb2tlLW1pdGVybGltaXQ9IjEwIiB4MT0iNDIiIHkxPSItMTcyMCIgeDI9IjQyIiB5Mj0iMTgzMiIvPg0KCTwvZz4NCjwvZz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-grid-icon[icon=facebook] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
  .bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage md-inline-grid-icon[icon=twitter] {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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'); }
```

I have added in the same bottom sheet html page in the link above and I am only trying to create the grid effect, not the list effect.

If anyone can spot what is wrong with the demo documentation or can shed some light on why it isnt working it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You must update your version of angular material to at least 0.7.1 available from the CDN using this script tag:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

I believe the error is due to a problem loading HammerJS due to a console reading I encountered that was an error to that effect. Regardless, here is a [working codepen](http://codepen.io/prescottprue/pen/qEyOde) with the code that you posted and the CDN reference to 0.7.1.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!

I've tried switching the CDN links for the style sheet as well as the js file. 

I was currently using version 0.8.2.. 

When I transer the exact code you have on the codepen locally, the 'show list' and 'show grid' dont show up as buttons but only text and they're not clickable. Here is a screenshot of what results I get locally using mamp. Thanks! http://imgur.com/9t5I5SY

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issues when I try to use angular locally. 
All I am seeing is {{alert}} when I try to use the dialog demo or the bottom sheet demo. I have also tried cloning the git account and still no success.